# Transferring huge files from SAS to hadoop - CSV

Tags: hadoop, sas, hue

I have exported a dataset from SAS and am trying to import the same file into Hadoop.
The dataset is in the format of csv.
It’s a huge file – 6GB

Issues – I am uploading the file through HUE – file import
After upload below issues occur:

1. Columns have overlapped values
   For ex : Col 1 -> A, col 2  B after upload Col 1  AB
2. Few columns have junk values  ? diamond and so on
3. Column datatypes are different

There are 400 variables so changing one of the variable in the dataset is very tedious

Is there any way we can upload huge csv file with the data(columns and values intact)

Comment: I assume you don't have the SAS Access for Hadoop module licensed?

Comment: Do you have a SAS/ODBC license? Why aren't you connecting via SAS and uploading it directly? If you are importing and exporting a CSV you also need to ensure the encoding is the same - what encoding is each system using?

Comment: Yes....its not licensed..How do u check the encoding? I do nt specify any parameters while downloading or uploading ..Code for SAS:                                                      
 Proc export data= work.data
   outfile= '*.csv'
   dbms = CSV
   replace;
            delimiter=",";
run;

Comment: In SAS to export with a specific encoding you would use a `file` ref to specify the encoding and then use proc export. Hadoop uses UTF-8 by default I believe, not sure what SAS or your system uses.

Comment: Exported data from sas in UTF - 8 format..now uploading in Hadoop...will  post teh results once done?

Comment: Do any of your character variables contain either CR ('0D'x) or LF ('0A'x) characters? SAS will not automatically add quotes around such values when writing delimited files.  Might be best to replace them with some other character first.

Comment: I tried downloading data from sas in UTF - 8 format and then uploading onto hadoop, I still that the column values are overlapped...

Comment: Tom : Can I remove the CR and LF characters while exporting  data from SAS?

Comment: filename output 'AAA.csv' encoding="utf-8";


Proc export data= input_data
   outfile= output
   dbms = CSV;
run;
 how to add the piece code to remove LF and CR here?

Comment: I tried exporting data from sas and then upload to sas again..even then the data imported is not correct. So I believe the problem lies in exporting...how do I export the columns and its value intact....